# Is it possible to overlay timestamped data around specific events in R graphs?

Tags: r

I want to figure out when before events (e.g. an exam) a platform gets used.

I have a lot of access data from two years

```
2018-09-02 14:46:56 #earliest log
2020-10-12 23:30:13 #last log
```

and loads of events within those years I would like to look at. e.g.:

```
2019-11-26 15:00:00
2019-12-19 15:00:00
2020-01-22 08:30:00
```

I managed to graph one event (red line) and what happens around it (in this case up to 48h prior).

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = earliestlog)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 700)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.POSIXct("2019-10-23 09:00:00")),
             color="red", linetype="dashed", size=0.5)+
  xlim(as.POSIXct("2019-10-21 09:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2019-10-24 09:00:00"))
```

[image: resulting graph]

What I now want is to do this for all events and have it overlayed with all events basically being the same red line so I am able to see what happens in the weeks prior. Can be a density plot or whatever really.

Since I am working with date and timestamps I don't know if there is a smart way to do this. I was thinking of manipulating all dates between events (converting everything between events to let's say 1.1.2022-31.1.2022) so that they in the end can be graphed, but that's obviously not a very neat solution and events are not evenly spaced, so I don't think it would work.

Here is my log data in grey and my moments which I want to overlay in red.

[image: what needs to be overlayed]

The time should not be manipulated as overlaying a 9am and 12pm event would obviously shift the data from the logs leading up to the 12pm event back by 3 hours.

Any idea if this is doable?

my second df (exam) contains all 77 exam datetimesin the column exam$start.

This is what I think my code needs to do:

```
select a row from exam$start, select that datetime 

select all rows from df where (df$earliestlog >= exam$start-days(31)) & (df$earliestlog <= exam$start) #this should get all logs from the month prior up to the exam date

paste into new df, but adjust dates to dates of past month 

and then repeat this until it has done this for all 77 exam moments in exam$start
```

That should leave me with a dataset that has all the timestamps adjusted to the past month which I can then easily plot as they basically overlay automatically.

Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
structure(list(session_id = c(19L, 19L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 28L, 28L
), moduleid = c(397L, 902L, 690L, 1698L, 1755L, 1271L, 1280L), 
    numslidesread = c(1L, 1L, 31L, 31L, 44L, 3L, 6L), totalsecondsspent = c(5L, 
    13L, 1607L, 1903L, 556L, 34L, 327L), earliestlog = structure(c(1535901815.913, 
    1535901806.71, 1535908234.25, 1535908317.923, 1535910210.9, 
    1535917280.053, 1535916929.16), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you have a list of events you want to notate with red lines, overlaid over a histogram of event log data? It sounds like you might want to use different data frames for each, e.g. `geom_vline(LIST_OF_NOTATION_TIMES, aes(xintercept = timestamps, color = category), linetype = "dashed") +...`

Comment: Yes I have a list of events, the red line was more symbolic to explain that I want the data of the month from before each event overlayed with the events being the same x axis value.

Comment: So is the red line derivable from the log data? If so, what logic do you want to use to define it?

Comment: No, exam moments are not derivable from the data logs. 

I have continuous data logs from two years. I want to use a list of 70 exam dates (e.g. 2019-11-26 15:00:00) to break up the data and overlay it 70 times so to speak and have basically 70 red lines on top of each other and then to the left of the red line I see everything that happens leading up to the exams.

Comment: I added a picture of the entire data above. In grey there is the logs, when the platform is used. in red there are exam moments. 

I basically want to find any way to make all the red lines one so that I can see what happens the days before an exam, not just with a single instance but taking all exams together.

Comment: So is the idea to join the two data sets and re-express the timestamps in `df` in terms of "hours until next exam" so that all of the logs can be expressed on a common timescale?

Comment: Sure, we can do that, I really don't mind how we get there. Just wanna see user behaviour in the days leading up to an exam. The question is does this work when there is only a few days between exam moments? I wanted to copy the hole month of data from before every moment to a new df and basically adjust the dates all to this month. See idea above. Again, no clue if this is a smart solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your latest comments, you want to express the log volume in terms of "time until next exam."

I think this can be done straightforwardly by merging your log data and your exam data to define a new variable showing "time until next exam."

Here's some example data:

```
set.seed(42)
logs <- data.frame(
  status = "log",
  timestamps = as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 00:00", tz = "UTC") + runif(100, max = 30*24*60*60)
  )

exams <- data.frame(
  status = "exam",
  timestamps = as.POSIXct(c("2022-01-05 12:00", "2022-01-31 14:00"), tz = "UTC")
)
```

We can then bind those two data sets together (with compatible "timestamps" variables), arrange, and fill in the next exam time so it appears in each row. Then we can plot using that as our time variable.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(logs, exams) %>%
  arrange(timestamps) %>%
  mutate(next_exam = if_else(status == "exam", timestamps, NA_POSIXct_)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(next_exam, .direction = "up") %>%
  mutate(hrs_vs_exam = as.numeric(timestamps - next_exam)/(60*60)) %>%
  filter(status == "log") %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(hrs_vs_exam)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 24, boundary = 0)
```